# Bypass maximum level on item enchant

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to enchant an item with Smite level 100 with commands, but i cant get past the maximum level. I searched for solutions, and tried them out, but it still won't work. I'm using Minecraft Pocket Edition.
The command I've tried was: `/enchant @a [r=4] 10 100`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get higher enchantments than the limit in the pocket edition of minecraft without using external tools that are able to modify your save files.

Comment: Could you recommend me some? Thanks

Comment: I don´t use any, so I can´t recommend anything. I found this after a quick search: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wyCQm5U8vA I do NOT know that app, I do NOT know if it´s safe, if it works, or anything, but it looks like it lets you make enchantments higher than the limit in minecraft pocket edition. **I recommend researching it before you install it, to make sure it´s safe**

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it get toolbox for mcpe or mcpe master those apps can get you past the enchantment limit it can enchant any sword higher then 4 to 5 or 6 enchantment level

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you put after @a a space *then* You put the Radius, while the command expects an Enchantment name or an Enchantment ID. 
instead, you should input the following:

IF in the chat type this: `/enchant @s 10 100`

IF in Command Block type this: `enchant @p 10 100`  
and put an activation method via Redstone next to the command block

Comment: It still wont work i want to get past the level limit but everything ive tried still wont bypass the limit

Comment: And btw it worked perfectly before i just want to bypass the limit